# When exactly should I refresh the EWS URL while using managed API

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, autodiscovery

I am getting the EWS URL as below:

```
var response = myAutodiscoverService.GetUserSettings(
                        "userA@domain.com",
                        UserSettingName.ExternalEwsUrl,
                        UserSettingName.InternalEwsUrl,
                        UserSettingName.EwsSupportedSchemas);

string settingValue;
if (response.TryGetSettingValue(UserSettingName.ExternalEwsUrl, out settingValue)
    || response.TryGetSettingValue(UserSettingName.InternalEwsUrl, out settingValue))
{
    // If ExternalEwsUrl is not returned in the response, 
    // we consider InternalEwsUrl for auto-discover
    string ewsurl = settingValue;
}
```

Now, I am caching this ewsurl I get with this request as recommended since auto-discovery is really slow. What happens when this ewsurl expires (because let's say user's mailbox was moved to a different endpoint). What error should I expect in order to implement a failure mechanism to get the new updated ews url?

Edit: I am using the ews url to subscribe for new mail events on EWS using `ExchangeService.SubscribeToPushNotifications` So I have another question, suppose if the ews url was changed after user subscribed for notifications, will I get a notification for that user for a new mail event on the callback url of my application?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall the ROT from MSFT was you should re-autodiscover every 24 hours, but I've not seen anything recently.  As to the Push notifications:  since there is a "heartbeat" facility in Push notifications, if you miss two heartbeats in a row, it's safe to say you should tear down the subscription and re-subscribe, which to be safe, implies re-autodiscovery.  Of course with O365, since the EWS URL seems (for now) to always be the same, re-autodiscovery is less of a concern.

Comment: yeah, I can see that MS recommends refreshing the EWS URL every 24 hours, but I have not seen it getting changed for any of our customers in very long time. So I was thinking if I get a specific error while requesting for subscription with an expired EWS URL, I would just do an auto-discovery in case of that error otherwise will keep using the cached EWS URL

Comment: yeah, but the problem is I can nowhere find what error I would get in case of an expired EWS URL

Comment: My experience has been that you get ErrorProxyRequestNotAllowed, which is an indication that the mailbox has moved and the CAS you've been going to can no longer handle requests on its behalf.  OTOH, it just might be safer to re-AD on any error you get on re-subscribe.